# Uninstalling Oracle WebLogic plugin from Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, oracle, plugins, weblogic, galileo

I believe that installing the Eclipse plugin for WebLogic changes the Eclipse behavior somewhat based on my experience with SSL handshake errors due to untrusted certs. I am trying to uninstall the Oracle WebLogic plugin from my Galileo installation. Here is the problem:
I see the Oracle WebLogic plugins and features when i click on help->InstallNewSoftware->Already Installed in the tabs named "plug-ins" and "features".
Those two tabs do not have the uninstall option/button at the bottom, but I do not see any listing for Oracle Enterprise and/or WebLogic plugin in the 'installed software' tab. This is the only place from where I can safely uninstall the plugin instead of just manually removing the plugin and features from the eclipse corresponding folders.

Is there some other entity managing the downloads from Oracle? is anyone else trying to do the same and finding similar problems? if you have any hints/pointers that'll be great -- Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the plugins and features for Oracle tools and WebLogic included, from the corresponding Eclipse folders, and started eclipse with -clean. Everything is executing fine so far.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the Oracle WebLogic Server Tools in the following way:
In the Servers view "New Server"->"Download additional server adapters"->"Oracle WebLogic Server Tools". Then when I want to uninstall I cannot find it in the installed plugin or features list, just like you.

Then I tried to search "Oracle WebLogic Server Tools" in Eclipse Marketplace, I can find "Oracle WebLogic Server Tools" with the option "Uninstall".

I believe this way of uninstallation is safe.